# To load an image in a frame in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to load an image in a specific frame, so that when I zoom in and out, it should be within that frame, it should not come out of the boundary. I was able to achieve this using scroll view, but there are some white spaces when I pan the image after zooming into the image.I want to pan only through the image.

Answer (score 0):

On the latest features of Xamarin.Forms is pinch gesture inside a ContentPage, here is the official page:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pinch/

and for the entire project sample:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithGestures/PinchGesture

Here is an example of what you can achieve:

Xamarin.Forms Pinch Example

Comment: But that pinch gesture should be within a frame and not the entire screen, how to resolve that?

Comment: and also I want to implement pinch gesture as well two buttons to zoom in and zoom out